# About new objects

Tags: java, android, object, cloning

I have a base object in a game that is used for stats. I copy the object each time I start a battle for the 40 sum units on the battle map.

I then modify the stats object for each unit. I of course do not want to pass by reference. The base stats object is filled with about 50 primitives. So I have created a constructor class of the object and have tediously gone and done copied each primitive. This seemed the safest way from what I found googling.

*Example Code*

```
class Stats{
int x;
int y;
int b;

public Stats(Stats stats)
{
this.x = stats.x;
this.y = stats.y;
this.b = stats.b;
}
}

Stats currentUnit = new Stats (currentUnitBaseStats);
```

**-questions-**

This is extremely frustrating and messy. Is it worth my time to look into implementing the built in cloning function?

If my stats class eventually contains other objects, will all objects contained within it also need to implement the cloning function?

Is there an easier way??

Side questions: on Android holding 40 separate classes of 100~ primitives is still pretty low on RAM consumption right?
Thanks and I love you guys :)

Comment: OOO also what about objects I didn't program too, like ArrayLists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have so many primitives (50) why don"t you use a HashMap ? :

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> stats = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    stats.put("x",3);
    stats.put("y",4);
    stats.put("z",5);
    stats.put("b",9);
    HashMap<String, Integer> statsCopy = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    statsCopy.putAll(stats);//this will copy all the values from the base object
}
```

Comment: O, thats an awesome idea. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey thanks, you basically did "solve" my issue, but showed me a much better way. Thank you so much. I know feel like I have wasted a good deal of time, but whatever thats life. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to implement your Stats class.  It may seem frustrating and messy, but functionally, that class is very simple.

If the stat values never chance, you could consider making Stats a static class.  Then, you never need to copy it.  For example:

```
static class Stats
{
    private int x = 10;
    private int y = 12;
    private int b = 13;
    ...
    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public int getB()
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

To get these values, you would call Stats.getX(), and would never have to instantiate the Stats class.  The downside is that Stats would be the same for all objects referencing it.

If you need independent stat values, you should use your current implementation.

If the starting values are the same for all stat Objects, you could create an additional constructor to set those values.

```
class Stats{
    int x;
    int y;
    int b;

    public Stats()
    {
        this.x = 10;
        this.y = 11;
        this.b = 12;
    }
}
```

To answer your second question, 40 Objects with 100 primitives would take a maximum of 32,000 bytes, or ~32KB, assuming they were all doubles.  On modern hardware, that shouldn't be a problem, however if you can reuse your data, I encourage you to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the values need to be changed, but I think I will use the hashmap instead. Thanks for addressing my RAM consumption. I attempt to whittle down the amount of memory I use as much as possible. I find that act very pleasing lol. But as i go forth in really making a game rather than an app, i am finding that it is better to give up ground in that area. its hard, but i am learning to let go of perfect optimization for working code lol :)